# Division method of hashing

Tags: hash, hashtable

Does anybody know why if hashed data with with m = 2, I should write h(k) = k mod 2^p(where p is lowest-order bits of k), but if hashed data with m > 2(5,20,44) to write h(k) = k mod 5? I know that we should avoid m = 2. And what is it "power of 2", "m shouldn't be power of 2"?
k - key
m - size of hash table
p - lowest-order bits of k

Comment: Please define m,k and p before reasoning about them.

Comment: @wildplasser  changed my question